# python xml - how to insert element from another xml

Tags: python, xml

I have simplified target xml like this:

```
<workflow>
    <tasks>
        ...
    </tasks>
</workflow>
```

Then I have source xml, with elements:

```
<task>
    <description>description</description>
    <name>test task 1</name>
    <sysID>410d6c0bc0a8</sysID>
    <type>Windows</type>
    <version>2</version>
</task>
<task>
    <description>description</description>
    <name>test task 2</name>
    <sysID>410d6880c0a8</sysID>
    <type>Windows</type>
    <version>9</version>
</task>
```

Would anybody recomend me, what is the best way to insert task from source file to tasks in target file?

What I have to do is to compose whole xml file like that.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What I came up with is to create template, with placeholders and insert tasks, triggers and so on on their place. I wondered if there is some smarter way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

src_tree = ET.parse('src.xml')
src_tasks = src_tree.findall('.//task')

target_tree = ET.parse('target.xml')
target_tasks_root = target_tree.find('.//tasks')

for src_task in src_tasks:
    target_tasks_root.append(src_task)

ET.dump(target_tree)
```

src.xml

```
<tasks>
    <task>
        <description>description</description>
        <name>test task 1</name>
        <sysID>410d6c0bc0a8</sysID>
        <type>Windows</type>
        <version>2</version>
    </task>
    <task>
        <description>description</description>
        <name>test task 2</name>
        <sysID>410d6880c0a8</sysID>
        <type>Windows</type>
        <version>9</version>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

target.xml

```
<workflow>
    <tasks>

    </tasks>
</workflow>
```

output

```
<workflow>
    <tasks>

    <task>
        <description>description</description>
        <name>test task 1</name>
        <sysID>410d6c0bc0a8</sysID>
        <type>Windows</type>
        <version>2</version>
    </task>
    <task>
        <description>description</description>
        <name>test task 2</name>
        <sysID>410d6880c0a8</sysID>
        <type>Windows</type>
        <version>9</version>
    </task>
</tasks>
</workflow>
```